# Check if a linked SQL server is running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am writing a stored procedure which runs `SELECT` queries on several different linked servers using the 4-dot notation.

The problem is, if one of the linked servers is not running, the query fails with error 121 `('The semaphore timeout period has expired')`.  The other `SELECT` queries then don't run as this error stops the rest of the query executing.

I wanted to check `@@ERROR` then continue running the other queries.

How can I continue running the query if the connection to one of the linked servers fails?

I am using SQL 2012.

Comment: Welcome to linked servers, better know as The High Unavailability Solution. Try to design a solution w/o a linked server.

Comment: @Tim have you tried using [TRY CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442772/sql-server-catch-exception-and-continue .  Is that the jist of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Did you look at [`sp_testlinkedserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189809.aspx)?

Comment: Sample code for `sp_testlinkedserver` here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/07/426578.aspx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to surround your single call with TRY-CATCH exception blocks?

```
     BEGIN TRY
          --First Server Connection (Server1) 192.168.1.x
          --If the connection isn't available it will raise an exception
          exec sp_testlinkedserver  @servername = Server1
          --SQL statement here
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
          SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
     END CATCH

     BEGIN TRY
          --Second Server Connection (Server2) 192.168.2.x
          --If the connection isn't available it will raise an exception
          exec sp_testlinkedserver  @servername = Server2
          --SQL statement here
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
          SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
     END CATCH
```

[sp_testlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189809.aspx)  will raise an exception inside a try block before the execution of your code but it won't stop the execution of the stored procedure.

Comment: Pretty sure this will still timeout, and not all linked server errors will be caught. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36178/linked-server-error-not-caught-by-try-catch

Comment: @AaronBertrand you're definitely right, I'm going to edit my code