# check whether linked server is valid in function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

We have a function that needs to select items from a linked server, like

```
Alter function dbo.ttest1()
    returns int
as
begin
    SELECT * FROM LINKED_SERVER.Database.Schema.Table
    WHERE .....
    RETURN 0
end
```

In case of the remote server is not available, the function will throw out the error saying connection failed, but I want to cover it and let it return a default value.

Since this is compile-level error, `BEGIN TRY --- END TRY` is not able to cover it, what's worse, since we are in function, `EXEC(@string)`,`sp_executesql`, `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('...')`, `sp_testlinkedserver` none of them works. the worst, I cannot afford to take risk of changing it into an SP (the grammar `SELECT dbo.ttest1()` is penetrated everywhere in the project).

Are there any good solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a linked SQL server is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528902/check-if-a-linked-sql-server-is-running)

Comment: The problem with attempting to check whether the server is available is that any such function doesn't answer the question "can my query run successfully?" but rather "was the remote server available a short while ago?". Once you've obtained the answer but before you can act on the answer, the external reality may have changed (e.g. server could go down, network issues could appear, etc)