# Find Unclosed XML tags in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am using SQL Server's CONVERT XML function to convert a string to XML.  The input string sometimes has bad data in it, and I need to clean it within a function in SQL Server.

The data looks like this:

```
<a>test</a>test<b>test
```

and converted with this:

```
select CONVERT(XML,'<a>test</a>test<b>test')
```

When using CONVERT, this errors with 'Unexpected end of input.'  The b tag isn't even a tag at all, just something somebody typed along with the valid XML.

I need to either get rid of the b tag it or put a slash on the end so it is a self-closing tag.

Is there any way in SQL Server to identify unclosed tags?  The only way I can figure out is to write my own XML parser...not something I want to do right now.  The data is already in SQL Server, so fixing it on user input isn't a possibility.

Any help would be appreciated.

ETA:  Bit the bullet and just parsed it. Very pedantic code below. Note this will not fix all unclosed tags...only ones that have NO closing tag anywhere with that name.  Anyone wishing to truly find unclosed tags...good luck!

Any improvements to this code are welcome!

```
DECLARE @OPENTAGS TABLE (
    tag VARCHAR(64)
);
DECLARE @CLOSETAGS TABLE (
    tag VARCHAR(64)
);

DECLARE @P INT=0;
DECLARE @Tag VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @IsOpen INT=0;
DECLARE @IsClosingTag INT=0;
DECLARE @C nchar(1);

WHILE @P<LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @C = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@P+1,1)
    IF @IsOpen=0
    BEGIN
        IF @C='<'
        BEGIN
            SET @IsOpen=1;
            SET @IsClosingTag=0;
            SET @Tag='';
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @C='/'
        BEGIN
            IF LEN(@Tag)=0
            BEGIN
                SET @IsClosingTag=1;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @IsOpen=0;
                SET @Tag='';
            END
        END
        IF @C='>'
        BEGIN
            IF @IsClosingTag=0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @OPENTAGS (tag) VALUES(@Tag)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @CLOSETAGS (tag) VALUES(@Tag)
            END
            SET @IsOpen=0;
            SET @Tag='';
        END
        IF (ASCII(@C)>=65 AND ASCII(@C)<=90) OR (ASCII(@C)>=97 AND ASCII(@C)<=122)
        BEGIN
            SET @Tag=@Tag+@C;
        END
    END
    SET @P = @P + 1;
END

IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tag) FROM @OPENTAGS) > (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tag) FROM @CLOSETAGS)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @@badtag nvarchar(64);
    DECLARE badtags CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT * FROM @OPENTAGS WHERE tag NOT IN (SELECT tag FROM @CLOSETAGS);
    OPEN badtags;
    FETCH NEXT FROM  badtags INTO @@badtag;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString,'<' + @@badtag + '>', '<' + @@badtag + '/>');
        FETCH NEXT FROM badtags INTO @@badtag;
    END;
    CLOSE badtags;
    DEALLOCATE badtags;
END
```

Comment: Maybe you can catch the exceptions and let the query continue?  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442772/sql-server-catch-exception-and-continue.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, there's nothing built-in.  As you found out, SQL Server can tell that XML is invalid.  What it can't do, is tell you exactly where.  Best you can do is catch the error, write the bad data to some "reject" table, then parse the rejects outside of SQL to find out where the problem is.